# how to change default values of axis to user values

Tags: c#, teechart

I have created multiple Y-axis in chart and individual scales for each axis by default. Now if user(i) wants to change those default values. I have created one form with textbox for entering scale min and max values.
I have attached an image please have a loot at the image.
[image]

now i want to get that text box value and assign to min and max scale of each axis. 
Can anyone have the idea how to do it . please help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can modify axis scales using SetMinMax method, for example:

```
  tChart1.Axes.Custom[0].SetMinMax(min, max);
```

For more information about axis settins please read tutorial 4. Tutorials can be found at TeeChart's program group. For multiple custom axis you may be interested in reading [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14692012/teechart-multiple-axis-creation).

Comment: Yes i want to plot graph as shown in the image. In the image you can see there are check boxes at the bottom of chart then if i click any check box then that sensor Y-axis with assigned color is appearing in the graph with difftent scale. I am trying to plot like that. the previous one is not the one i want.

Comment: @ramjaya ok, please try using the code Yeray Alonso posted at the question I pointed. You just need to make axes visible subject to series visibility and color with legend's click event.

Comment: Calvet Thanks for your help, I will try to do that. I am sorry if it is related to same question then i will remove this question.

Comment: Can you have a look at my new problem which i have edited today.

Comment: Hi, sorry for asking you once again. I need a small help which is, I am displaying sensor names as series names in the legend box. you can see in the above picture. when i click check box then the axis of that series is displaying with default scales. now i am trying to change scales of each axis through by clicking a button"axis". Is it possible to get dynamically the names which are displaying in the legend to this "Axis" button form. In the above picture i have created label and named it with sensors. So i thought its not generic. what i have to do to display the names here also.

Comment: @ramjaya yes, you can use the LegendClicked event, for example:
    void tChart1_ClickLegend(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
      int index = tChart1.Legend.Clicked(e.X, e.Y);
      Steema.TeeChart.LegendItem li = tChart1.Legend.Items[index];
      string text = li.Text;
    }